# Confusion in working with monitors in java

Tags: java, synchronization

I'm trying to understand how exactly you use a monitor in Java. As far as I can tell, Java doesn't provide a monitor you can create like you would with a Binary or Counting Semaphore. Since this is the case, what exactly does it mean when I see people do something like:

```
while(!B){ 
    x.wait(); 
}
```

What exactly could x be in this case? Is it some class they built that mimics monitor action that has a wait() method?

Why not just do this

```
while(!B){
    wait();
}
```

? Is it it so you can have multiple monitors? If so, why? It seems like at this point you might as well just use a semaphore...

Overall I think my issue is really understanding what a monitor is and how you properly use it. I appreciate any insight you can give me.

Comment: what about reading a java tutorial on multimthteading?

Comment: @AlexWien That's what I've been doing but I'm finding myself confused with monitor operation as is described in my reading

Comment: It is pretty confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wait()` is a method of `java.lang.Object`. Every Java object has an instrinsic lock, called the monitor.

`x.wait()` waits on the object references by the variable `x`. `wait()` is equivalent to `this.wait()`, and thus waits on the object referenced by `this`.

That said, `wait()` is a very low-level and hard to use abstraction. You'd better use higher-level abstraction, like a... `Semaphore`, which Java has. Check it out in the javadoc.

Also check out [Java's concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/), which covers these topics.